# Create a directory in a spring boot application built with cloud native buildpack to run on kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, local-storage, apache-kafka-streams, buildpack

I need to create a specific directory in an image built with a cloud-native build pack. It's a spring-boot application and I use the standard cloud-native build pack included with it.

With a Dockerfile this is a snippet of how I would do it:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
RUN mkdir -p /data/stream-price-service
RUN addgroup kstream && useradd -m kstream -g kstream
RUN chown -R kstream:kstream /data/stream-price-service
USER kstream:kstream
```

So when the application starts it has access and ownership over the folder `/data/stream-price-service` and can use it as it's local storage location.

So with buildpack I also need that when the container starts the directory `data/stream-price-service` exists and is rw for the spring-boot application. I have tried using the `<directories>` configuration but it doesn't create the directory:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <name>stream-price-service</name>
        </image>
        <directories>/data/stream-price-service</directories>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The above configuration doesn't work.

Using spring boot build pack to create the image, how to create the directory structure and assign ownership so when the container starts it's available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the buildpack runs as a non-root user and group called `cnb`. It cannot create arbitrary directories under root, like `/data`. It can only create directories within certain locations, like `/layers` (where buildpacks install things) or `/workspace` (where the application lives, although this is not recommended).

When your application runs, it will execute as the `cnb` user and group also, this provides you similar access to where you can write things as the buildpack. For enhanced security, the generated OCI image can be run as a different user. In this case, you can only write to locations that are group writable or world-writable (like `/tmp`).

Best case, you can change your application to write somewhere else. Make the directory configurable (`@Value` or `@ConfigurationProperties`), Spring is very flexible so you can pass in config through env variables, system properties, or arguments. Then write to that location instead.

If you can't change the location, it gets more difficult. At the moment, there's not an easy way to change the base image. You would essentially need to create a custom run image.

The [full process to create a custom stack is here](https://buildpacks.io/docs/operator-guide/create-a-stack/#specification), however, you don't need a full stack, just a custom run image.

If you base off of the Paketo run image you're presently using, like `paketobuildpacks/builder:base` or `paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny`, you can add the location you need to the custom run image, change the permissions to be read/write for the `cnb` user, and then [switch the run image when you build](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.6/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization) with the `runImage` property with Spring Boot builds or the `--run-image` flag with `pack build`.

To base off one of the Paketo images, just create a Dockerfile and add `FROM <paketo-run-image>`.

Ex:

```
FROM paketobuildpacks/run:base-cnb

USER root
RUN mkdir /data && chown cnb:cnb /data
USER cnb
```

Then `pack build cool-image --run-image custom-run-base`.

Comment: Daniel Mikusa - I am wondering now if it's just not an issue with containers so pls let me know. The problem with /tmp is that it gets deleted automatically after 10 days in most linux distros.... BUT in a container this might actually not matter as if the content is mapped to an external volume and re-atached on container creation it should be fine right? I have never tried though and based on previous exp it just feels like bad practice to have persistent storage (rocksdb files in this case) in the tmp directory.

Comment: Gotcha. In a container, you would not want to write something important to the local file system. Even if you write it to `/var/data` or some other more classical location, that will disappear after the container exits. Docker muddles this a bit as it does not immediately purge your container after it exits, but if you move to run inside Kubernetes it will clean up your container after it exits. As you said, the way to handle this is by mapping in an external volume. Even in Docker, it's a good practice to map in an external volume.

Comment: If you map in `/data` as an external volume, you should not have the same permission issues either because you can control the ownership.

Comment: You are right, I used `tiny-cnb` by mistake, but realized it in meantime. Managed to build image with writable `/data` folder in the end. Everything works as you said, thanks. But just to add that I needed to add `pullPolicy = "IF_NOT_PRESENT"` to bootBuildImage config (this was not obvious to me for some time, so I lost some time thinking what is wrong). Also, I was totally puzzled that, if you use some folder under `/workspace` like e.g. /workspace/logs` app works. At least as long as you do not mount any volume on that. For some reason, if you mount generic volume app loses permissions?!

Comment: Yes, you really, really want to avoid trying to mount a volume to a location that has existing data or might potentially conflict with files in the container. If you're really careful you can do that, but it can cause problems like you said with permissions (in container vs what set through the mounted volume) and with uid/gid. It can also shadow files in the container, which can be a security problem (maybe it masks a newer file?) or it can just break stuff if it hides the wrong file. tl;dr the easy path is to pick a unique directory.

Comment: @DanielMikusa Could you explain, why it was possible that the Spring Boot 3.1.3 application could write into `/workspace`, but Spring Boot 3.1.9 cannot write into `/workspace`. I see, that the build user is now 1001 and the run user is now 1002, so all my service fail now. How can I write into the container with 3.1.9?

Comment: @DanielMikusa Unfortunately, I found no release notes, where it was written, that using `/workspace` is no more supported. I changed to `/tmp` and it seems to work. I hope it will work in future, too. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielMikusa For Apache Tomcat Buildpack there is a fix: https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/apache-tomcat/issues/238 Maybe Spring Boot should support something similar?

Comment: The change isn't related to Spring Boot or the Spring Boot buildpack, but to the stack. When you go from Spring Boot 3.1 to 3.1.9, you're changing stacks (Bionic, which is long out of support, to Jammy which is supported). See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v3.1.6. Build/run UID being different is a security feature added in Jammy, see https://paketo.io/docs/concepts/stacks/#what-security-and-hardening-features-do-paketo-stacks-offer.

Comment: The Tomcat issue you referenced is different. It is not writing to `/workspace`, but to a layer directory. Writing to `/tmp` is recommended, but if you must write to `/workspace` you can create a directory that is writable by the runtime UID and include that within your application files. It will inherit the local permissions in the container. The trick with Java apps is that you need to have that created and added to the JAR file produced by your build tool (Maven/Gradle). That is because the Boot Build tools will pass the compiled JAR file to buildpacks, which is then used as `/workspace`.